# Omitting loop while referring to next elements of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Let's consider the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2 , 5, 6, 4, 2, 1, 6])
```

I want to do the following thing: If i-th element of the dataframe is bigger than mean of two next, then we assign 1, and if not, we assign -1 to this ith element.

**My solution**

An obvious solution is the following:

```
df_copy = df.copy()
for i in range(len(df) - 2):
    
    if (df.iloc[i] > np.mean(df.iloc[(i+1):(i+2)]))[0]:
        df_copy.iloc[i] = 1
    else:
        df_copy.iloc[i] = -1
```

However, I find it little cumbersome, and I'm wondering if there is any loop-free solution to these kind of problems.

**Desired output**

```
    0
0   -1
1   -1
2   -1
3   1
4   1
5   -1
6   -1
7   1
8   1
9   1
10  1
11  6
```

Comment: can you add the desired output?

Comment: There you go ;))

Comment: how do you want to handle the last 2 elements that do not have enough further data to compute the mean?

Comment: Nothing should be done with them

Comment: Check if my answer works for you else I'll update for those 2 items

Comment: why is index ```4``` ```1``` in your desired output when ```3<np.mean([2,5])```? did you mean to do ```df.iloc[(i+1):(i+3)]```?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`rolling.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.mean.html) and [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df['out'] = np.where(df[0].gt(df[0].rolling(2).mean().shift(-2)), 1, -1)
```

output:

```
    0  out
0   1   -1
1   2   -1
2   3   -1
3   4    1
4   3   -1
5   2   -1
6   5   -1
7   6    1
8   4    1
9   2   -1
10  1   -1
11  6   -1
```

##### keeping last items unchanged:

```
m = df[0].rolling(2).mean().shift(-2)
df['out'] = np.where(df[0].gt(m), 1, -1)
df['out'] = df['out'].mask(m.isna(), df[0])
```

output:

```
    0  out
0   1   -1
1   2   -1
2   3   -1
3   4    1
4   3   -1
5   2   -1
6   5   -1
7   6    1
8   4    1
9   2   -1
10  1    1
11  6    6
```